# RBing - Child-safe image search

Tags: ruby, bing, bing-api

How can you search Bing for child-safe images using [RBing](https://github.com/mikedemers/rbing)?

I see that the Bing API has an [`AdultOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251007), but I don't see any way to use this option with RBing.

Answer (score 2):

Set `:adult`

```
require 'rbing'                                                                
require 'active_support/inflector'                                             

bing = RBing.new(YOUR_ACCOUNT_KEY)
bing.search('image', 'sex', :adult => "Strict" )

# or another way
bing.image('sex', :adult => "Strict")
# => {"results"=>[]}
bing.image('hump', :adult => "Strict")['results'].size
# contains 50 kid safe images
# => 50
```

By the way, I had to use travisp's 2.0-pre fork to get this to work because of the APPID migration issue that is going on.  So if the original gem doesn't work use [this one](https://github.com/travisp/rbing/tree/features/azure), the features/azure branch in which my account key worked instead of the deprecated APPID.

To install travisp 2.0 pre fork gem do the following.

```
gem install rbing-2.0.0.pre
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this to install the right gem.

> gem install rbing-2.0.0.pre